# How to add DLL file to pyinstaller packaging?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-packaging

**Question**: How do I specify in Pyinstaller to add a (dll) file to compile, that it otherwise cannot find? The goal is to have a working .exe file.

**Background**: I am trying to compile a Python app with Pyinstaller (Windows 10). The code executes fine before compilation.

```
import teradatasql

# ESTABLISH CONNECTION
con =  teradatasql.connect(host='myhostaddress', 
            user='myuser',
            password='mypass'
            )
```

**Problem**: However, after compiling *it seems* that the traceback mentions that the "teradatasql.dll" file is missing (presumably this is the causes for the .exe failing to execute).

[image: traceback].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my team members wrote a [blog post about how to use PyInstaller to package the Teradata SQL Driver for Python](https://support.teradata.com/community?id=community_blog&sys_id=c327eac51b1e9c103b00bbb1cd4bcb37).

You need to specify PyInstaller's `--add-binary` option with a path argument for the `teradatasql.dll` file.